# Is there a Lawrence of Arabia Syndroome

Tags: personality

Let's call Lawrence of Arabia syndrome the following:

1. Maximizes the faults of one's own culture
2. Minimizes the achievements of one's own culture
3. Minimizes the faults of another culture
4. Maximizes the achievements of another culture

Have psychologists already named this syndrome?

Two contemporary people that can be described as having this would be Noam Chomsky and Roy Casagrande. Lt Dunbar in the fictional Dances of Wolves would be another.

Comment: Did you mean to reverse 3 and 4? I don't think there is a specific term for this. In general, the affix "philia" (love/fetish) is used, as in: "Arabophilia" (what Lawrence had), "Anglophilia" (England), "Japanophilia" (Japan; aka weaboo), "Philosemitism" (Jews), etc.

Comment: yes, I did, thanks for pointing that out.  No, adding the -philia wouldn't do it, because a Francophile, for example, can love both their own culture and French culture, but one who has Lawrence of Arabia syndrome would have to necessarily hate their own culture.

Comment: I've tried patriomania, but the usage doesn't seem to fit. Yours may just end up being a cut-and-fit for any particular situation/country without any standard versions yet coined or accepted by dictionaries.

Comment: Another problem is that I do not know whether TE Lawrence was anti-british, but there are certainly other intellectuals that fit the bill.  There's the term self-hating, but self-hating does not necessarily imply that you love someone else.